# How to read cross- domain iframe content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am embedding an iframe which has src ="" from another domain.

For example, my page is www.abc.com/Default.aspx, and the iframe

```
<iframe id="myFrame" src="www.xyz.com"></iframe>
```

All that I want to do is when I click on submit button of iframe from
then I should display an alert.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("button[type=submit]").click(function () {
           alert();
       });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: You cannot do it, iframe will have different DOM.

Comment: i just need alert an alert on whole  iframe click

Comment: Not possible. There are several security measure to stop you accessing cross-domain content through JS - for fairly obvious reasons.